# How to extract audio from mp4 python

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, wav

I have about `2K` **mp4** and **webm** files that I want to extract the `left-mono` and `right-mono` from them and save each one of them to `WAV` **STEREO** with `44100H` and `32bit`

I use this code but it saved it as `mono-left` and `mono-right`

```
os.system('ffmpeg -i "/content/46.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:a]channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo[left][right]" -map "[left]" left.wav -map "[right]" right.wav')
```

but I need the `left.wav` and `right.wav` saved as stereo file

Answer (score 0):

We need to import the moviepy package or the editor class alone specifically. Then we need to create a VideoFileClip object by referencing the video file through the parameter. Once this is done, extracting the audio is as simple as accessing the audio member of the VideoFileClip object that we created.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).